# MS Access SQL -> Count records in Table 1, Perform If condition in Table 2, but show all records

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I currently have an SQL statement that produces 3 columns:

```
    [Review Date] [Total Reviews] [Reviewed By]  

     10/24/2001         16            Jane
     10/24/2001         1             Bob
     10/24/2001         2             Chloe
     09/20/2001         17            Jane
     09/20/2001         34            Bob
     09/20/2001         86            Chloe
     02/04/2001         14            Jane
     02/04/2001         3             Bob
     02/04/2001         41            Chloe
```

The SQL looks like this (to get the above output):

```
SELECT 

[Review Results].[Review Date], 
count([Review Results].[Reviewed By]) as [Total Reviews], 
[Review Results].[Reviewed By]

FROM 
[Review Results]

GROUP BY  [Review Results].[Review Date], [Review Results].[Reviewed By]


ORDER BY [Review Results].[Review Date]
```

What I would like to do is join another table in called [Home_Days_table]. The table looks like this:

```
[Reviewed By]     [WFH Date]

   Jane           10/12/2011
   Jane           07/11/2010
   Bob            04/09/2002
   Jane           01/01/2007
```

I'm looking for the above query to populate the [WFH Date] field from the [Home_Days_Table], for every record that has a match between the [Results Review].[Review Date] & [Results Review].[Reviewed By] with the [Home_Days_Table].[Reviewed By] & [Home_Days_Table].[WFH Date]. I want to display all records from the original SQL above and append a column that satisfies this condition.

### Can someone help?

In addition to the above, I'm looking to perform the query as given but adding in another date field. The query I used was:

```
SELECT 
   [Review Results].[Review Date], 
   count([Review Results].[Reviewed By]) as [Total Reviews], 
   [Review Results].[Reviewed By], 
   [Home_Days_table].[WFH Date]

FROM [Review Results]
LEFT JOIN [Home_Days_table]
ON  [Review Results].[Reviewed By]=[Home_Days_table].[Reviewed By] 
AND [Review Results].[Review Date]=[Home_Days_table].[WFH Date]

GROUP BY  
   [Review Results].[Review Date], 
   [Review Results].[Reviewed By],
   [Home_Days_table].[WFH Date]


ORDER BY [Review Results].[Review Date]
```

This above query answered the original question, but I want to add in another column on top of the [WFH Date] called [Summer Days]. The idea is the same as the original question but I am looking for the query to now populate the [WFH Date] field from the [Home_Days_Table] and the [Summer Days] field from the [Home_Days_Table], for every record that has a match between the [Results Review].[Review Date] & [Results Review].[Reviewed By] with the [Home_Days_Table].[Reviewed By] & [Home_Days_Table].[WFH Date], and [Results Review].[Review Date] & [Results Review].[Reviewed By] with the [Home_Days_Table].[Reviewed By] & [Home_Days_Table].[Summer Days].

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

Something like .. ?

```
SELECT 
   [Review Results].[Review Date], 
   count([Review Results].[Reviewed By]) as [Total Reviews], 
   [Review Results].[Reviewed By], 
   [Home_Days_table].[WFH Date]

FROM [Review Results]
LEFT JOIN [Home_Days_table]
ON  [Review Results].[Reviewed By]=[Home_Days_table].[Reviewed By} 
AND [Review Results].[Review Date]=[Home_Days_table].[WFH Date]

GROUP BY  
   [Review Results].[Review Date], 
   [Review Results].[Reviewed By],
   [Home_Days_table].[WFH Date]


ORDER BY [Review Results].[Review Date]
```

Comment: I have one other twist to this query as noted in the question, do you know if this is possible?

Comment: Do you mean you just want to join [Review Results].[Review Date] to [Home_Days_table].[Summer Days] as well as the other joins, or is SummerDays to come from a subquery?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the FAQ comment. But yes, im looking to join [Review Results].[Review Date] to [Home_Days_table].[Summer Days] as well as the other joins

Comment: In that case, just put in another AND. `<...> AND [Review Results].[Review Date]=[Home_Days_table].[Summer Days]`